# String issue with ANSI code

Tags: python, string-formatting, ansi-escape

My goal is to visualize, for example, this output:

```
[ Sun, 09 06 2013 12:51:49 ]
```

The entire date must be colorized with this ANSI code:

```
\033[1m\x1b[32m DATE \x1b[0m\r
```

I tried with this piece of code:

```
import time

DATE = time.strftime("%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S", time.localtime())

OUTPUT = "[ " + "\033[1m\x1b[32m" + DATE + "\x1b[0m\r" + " ]"

print OUTPUT
```

But it returns me a string completely wrong:

[image]

What's wrong with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The carriage return `\r` in the string causes the cursor to be placed at the start of the line, so the `]` overwrites `[`.

Change it to this:

```
OUTPUT = "[ \033[1m\x1b[32m" + DATE + "\x1b[0m ]\r"
```

Comment: Oh, that was really easy. Sometimes even the most trivial problems can be truly intractable. Thank you so much.